# Libgdx for loop lag

Tags: android, libgdx

I have problems with my game. The game runs ok until the time where I have to reposition the objects, which happens every frame. For example here I have to reposition some parked cars (around 6 cars on each side of the road), the cars are constantly moving down in the screen, then they reset and reposition at the top again. I have used Poolable to save resources. However, the game is still very jumpy when it comes to running these lines of code. Is there any way I could improve the code to prevent lag? Maybe a new thread? If so how would be the right way of creating a new thread and updating it every frame.

```
private void updateParkedVehicles(float delta){
    for (int i = 0; i < parkedCarLeft1Array.size; i++){
        parkedCarLeft1Array.get(i).update(delta);

        for (int c = 0; c < parkedCarLeft1Array.size; c++){
            if (c != i){
                if (Intersector.overlaps(parkedCarLeft1Array.get(i).bounds, parkedCarLeft1Array.get(c).bounds)){
                    parkedCarLeft1Array.get(i).reset();

                }
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < parkedCarRight1Array.size; i++){
        parkedCarRight1Array.get(i).update(delta);

        for (int c = 0; c < parkedCarRight1Array.size; c++){
            if (c != i){
                if (Intersector.overlaps(parkedCarRight1Array.get(i).bounds, parkedCarRight1Array.get(c).bounds)){parkedCarRight1Array.get(i).reset();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle items in your game is through the use of the Scene2d.
Scene2D allows you to step out from having to move yourself the items. Instead you give them instructions (as a director would) if and when you need to move them instead of having to handle yourselve every frame update.

in a nutshell, to add an Action you would do this:

```
if(SomeCondition){
   MoveToAction moveCar = new MoveToAction();
   moveCar.setPosition(anX,anY);
   moveCar.setDuration(aDuration);
   myCarActor.addAction(moveCar);
}
```

That way, the only thing you need to check for is the occurence of the event and you call your function to move the car only once (when the event occurs).

LibGdx will take care of updating your actor each frame.
The only thing you will need to do in your loop is to check the collision. If they occur then you will assign a new Action to your actor.

Another thing to keep in Mind, if you use Scene2D is that you can use the Camera. This means that if you need to scroll, instead of moving each item, you simply move the camera (which has all the convenience method you need to zoom etc).

For more information on Scene2D check out: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/scene2d

For more information specifically on Actions check this out:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try that. I just wanted to point out that updating doesn't seem to be causing most of the problem. The lag seems to be mostly caused by the collision checking part. Which seems like is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is with double looping through arrays --> O(n^2) complexity!!

It's not clear for me why you need to check overlapping of each car with each car except this car if *"the cars are constantly moving down in the screen, then they reset and reposition at the top again"*. For the described behaviour the simplest way would be to check is the current y position is less that 0 and rest position if so:

```
for (Car car : parkedCarLeft1Array){
        car.update(delta);
        if (car.getY <= 0) {
            car.reset();
        }
    }
```

I assume that you update car position in `update()` method.

Comment: I have to check that the cars don't appear on top of each other before they go down to where the camera can see them. If the cars appear on top of each then they take a random position way high in the grid where the camera can't reach. If the car was to check for overlapping with itself then it would never go down. It would just reposition constantly. I do update the car position so it can go down in update() and also check if the car has gone below the camera there as well. For now what I have done is make the random range higher,  it helps but cars are not as close together.

Comment: It's hard for me to get what kind of game u're developing, but anyway I strongly suggest u to redesign this double looping part. As a suggestion: u may try to set each car initial position in some setup method (fill in arrays), then check for overlapping, and if it is - then change that car's position. Then in reset method u just reset the position using some constant Y value. In this case ur cars would never overlap each other.

Comment: @JorgeMenjívar any luck on my suggestion?